# How can Angular use custom attributes without the data-* prefix, and everyone else says you shouldn't?

Tags: angularjs, html, custom-data-attribute

Everyone (W3C validator, stackoverflow posts, etc) says you should prefix custom attributes with data- (e.g. data-my-custom-attr="hey"). And you shouldn't use them like: my-custom-attr="hey".

Yet Angular encourages you to use things like ng-click etc without the data- prefix.

Is this just a question of best practise? Or is Angular being a bit of a  maverick?..

Answer (score 0):

Why do you say that angular encourages it? In fact if you check `normalizations` section for directives in angular documentation you will find a note that angular in parsing directives strips `data-` and `x-` prefixes so you don't have to access attributes and name directives like

`.directive('dataMyCustomDirective', function(){})`

but nothing tells you you can't or shouldn't use `data-` or `x-` prefix if you want your HTML to be validated against w3c validator, i personally use attributes without the prefix in development and use grunt task to add prefix for production

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting question. But I think it's more of a personal use. I use a custom prefix for all the attrs and declarations I create with the company prefix. e.g. `mj-function` -> MyJob-Function. Nothing stops me from doing this ang ignoreing the `data-` prefix.

This also helps me keeping the code more organized (if using third part libs). Because it's easy to locate. `MJ` is code built by myself. `ng` is Angular. Other is third.

#### Keep an eye!

What you **have to** avoid is to declare your attrs with the prefix `ng` if you are using AngularJS, because then you could have a conflict with AngularJS main directives. Like ngClick, ngChange, ngBlur, etc...

But nothing about use/not use `data-` prefix.